# RFCOMM implementation on top of CoreBluetooth L2CAP on iOS 13

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

At WWDC 2019/iOS 13, Apple added support for legacy Bluetooth 2.0 devices to CoreBluetooth.

Some existing Bluetooth 2.0 devices implement RFCOMM, however CoreBluetooth itself lacks an RFCOMM API. What CoreBluetooth does offer is an L2CAP API.

**Since RFCOMM is normally implemented on top of L2CAP, in terms of the Bluetooth protocol stack, is it therefore viable to implement RFCOMM on iOS?**

As an aside, currently I am unable to get iOS to discover an advertising Bluetooth 2.0 peripheral which implements an RFCOMM interface. So there are additional technical challenges to be overcome as well.

Comment: Core Bluetooth does not support Bluetooth 2.0 in its entirety.  They added support for GATT on BR/EDR devices.  You can only use RFComm on iOS with MFi devices via the external connectivity framework.

Comment: Many thanks @Paulw11 - if you post this as an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Just to set expectations, the external accessory framework doesn't give you direct access to RFCOMM. It just gives you access to to iAP2 (which runs over RFCOMM).